# Reading of named settings from the XML

Tags: java, constants

Usually it is a good style in Java to create a named constant for a string (and other) hardcoded values. Using the example below I want to know how pedantic I should be in it.

I use a Java class as a wrapper of XML settings. Each function is suppose to return a value from a related XML file.

I defined a lot of constants with keys names on the top and each function use one single constant. Is it a good idea to remove constants and use hardcoded strings directly in each function?

Here is my settings file:

```
package com.art.backend.configs;

import com.art.backend.configs.inherited.Config;

public class ConfigStorage extends Config {

    private static final String SETTINGS_FILENAME = "storage.cfg.xml";

    private static final String KEY_HOST = "host";
    private static final String KEY_PORT = "port";
    private static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
    private static final String KEY_CONNECTION_TYPE = "connection_type";
    private static final String KEY_SEPARATOR= "separator";
    private static final String KEY_REMOTE_ROOT = "remote_root";
    private static final String KEY_SUBDIR_UPLOADED = "subdir_uploaded";

    public ConfigStorage() {
        super(SETTINGS_FILENAME);
    }

    public String getHost(){ return getString(KEY_HOST); }

    public int getPort(){ return getInt(KEY_PORT); }

    public String getUsername(){ return getString(KEY_USERNAME); }

    public String getPassword(){ return getString(KEY_PASSWORD); }

    public String getSeparator(){ return getString(KEY_SEPARATOR); }

    public String getConnectionType(){ return getString(KEY_CONNECTION_TYPE); }

    public String getRemoteRoot(){ return getString(KEY_REMOTE_ROOT); }

    public String getSubdirUploaded(){ return getString(KEY_SUBDIR_UPLOADED); }
}
```

Also I will attach file "Config" as a base class for my settings and XML settings file just in case, but they are not really important.

```
package com.art.backend.configs.inherited;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public abstract class Config {
    private static final String MSG_SETTING_NOT_FOUNT = "Settings file not found";

    private final String filename;
    private Properties properties = null;

    public Config(String filename){
        this.filename = filename;
        init();
    }

    private void init(){

        //Reading properties file in Java example
        try {
            properties = new Properties();
            InputStream fis = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("storage.cfg.xml");
            properties.loadFromXML(fis);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(MSG_SETTING_NOT_FOUNT);
        }
    }

    public String getFilename(){ return filename; }

    public String getString(String key){
        return properties.getProperty(key);
    }

    public int getInt(String key){
        return Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty(key));
    }

    public float getFloat(String key){
        return Float.parseFloat(properties.getProperty(key));
    }

    public boolean getBoolean(String key){
        return Boolean.parseBoolean(properties.getProperty(key));
    }
}
```

XML settings

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
    <entry key="host">***</entry>
    <entry key="port">***</entry>
    <entry key="username">***</entry>
    <entry key="password">***</entry>
    <entry key="connection_type">sftp</entry>
    <entry key="separator">/</entry>
    <entry key="remote_root">/home/adzhus/art_storage/</entry>
    <entry key="subdir_uploaded">uploaded/</entry>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your use case, where the constants are private and only ever used in one place, they are pretty much boilerplate. One could argue that the constants group the keys into one condense place where they can be referred to easily when reading code.

Answer (score 2):

As much as I agree with @TorbenPutkonen regarding the current state of the code, I would *not* go so far as to remove the constants.

They have one big advantage over having the strings in the methods, which is *being all in one place*.

If your config grows longer and more complex with an ongoing project, as eventually more complex methods creep into your config class (e.g. falling back to a calculated value or to a default value), your code will grow so that you don't see all the constants in a single glance anymore. *That* is the time, when you will be thankful for an overview of all keys at the top of the class.

For now, it's just YAGNI ;-)

Comment: I thought about that but the gist is "how often are the property names referred to?" Once the getter has been implemented, there isn't much need for the property name anymore. If you have to reverse engineer the config file (which is a problem in your process), then the single use private constant is just an extra hurdle.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, your implementation is good if you have a single xml file and only need one, here is some recommendations.

1) I suggest that you rename the class `Config` to `AbstractXmlConfig` or `XmlConfig` for readability, but it's up to you.

2) In the class `Config`, you can use the `filename` variable to load the xml / properties file; instead of using the hardcoded one. Also, i suggest that you inline the `init` method in the constructor.

**Inlined**

```java
    public Config(String filename){
        this.filename = filename;
        try {
            properties = new Properties();
            InputStream fis = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
            properties.loadFromXML(fis);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(MSG_SETTING_NOT_FOUNT);
        }
    }
```

**With method**

```java
    public Config(String filename){
        this.filename = filename;
        init(filename);
    }

    private void init(String filename) {
        try {
            properties = new Properties();
            InputStream fis = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
            properties.loadFromXML(fis);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(MSG_SETTING_NOT_FOUNT);
        }
    }
```

## Future proofing

1) For the methods that convert to a string, you can make an interface for them in case that you have multiple implementations of the `ConfigStorage`; in my opinion, it's always a big plus to be able to make custom data sources without refactoring the entire software to add a new type that not rely on the `Properties`.

```java
public interface ValueConverter {
    int getInt(String key);

    float getFloat(String key);

    boolean getBoolean(String key);
}
```

```java
public abstract class Config implements ValueConverter {
   //[...]
}
```

#### Full example

**XmlConfigStorageImpl**

```java
public class XmlConfigStorageImpl extends AbstractXmlConfig {

    private static final String SETTINGS_FILENAME = "storage.cfg.xml";
    private static final String KEY_HOST = "host";
    private static final String KEY_PORT = "port";
    private static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
    private static final String KEY_CONNECTION_TYPE = "connection_type";
    private static final String KEY_SEPARATOR= "separator";
    private static final String KEY_REMOTE_ROOT = "remote_root";
    private static final String KEY_SUBDIR_UPLOADED = "subdir_uploaded";


    public XmlConfigStorageImpl() {
        super(SETTINGS_FILENAME);
    }

    public String getHost(){ return getString(KEY_HOST); }

    public int getPort(){ return getInt(KEY_PORT); }

    public String getUsername(){ return getString(KEY_USERNAME); }

    public String getPassword(){ return getString(KEY_PASSWORD); }

    public String getSeparator(){ return getString(KEY_SEPARATOR); }

    public String getConnectionType(){ return getString(KEY_CONNECTION_TYPE); }

    public String getRemoteRoot(){ return getString(KEY_REMOTE_ROOT); }

    public String getSubdirUploaded(){ return getString(KEY_SUBDIR_UPLOADED); }
}
```

**AbstractXmlConfig**

```java
public abstract class AbstractXmlConfig implements ValueConverter {
    private static final String MSG_SETTING_NOT_FOUNT = "Settings file not found";

    private final String filename;
    private Properties properties;

    public AbstractXmlConfig(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
        init(filename);
    }

    private void init(String filename) {
        try {
            properties = new Properties();
            InputStream fis = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
            properties.loadFromXML(fis);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(MSG_SETTING_NOT_FOUNT);
        }
    }

    public String getFilename() {
        return filename;
    }

    public String getString(String key) {
        return properties.getProperty(key);
    }

    @Override
    public int getInt(String key) {
        return Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty(key));
    }

    @Override
    public float getFloat(String key) {
        return Float.parseFloat(properties.getProperty(key));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getBoolean(String key) {
        return Boolean.parseBoolean(properties.getProperty(key));
    }
}
```

**ValueConverter**

````java
public interface ValueConverter {
    int getInt(String key);

    float getFloat(String key);

    boolean getBoolean(String key);
}

```
````

Answer (score 2):

> Usually it is a good style in Java to create named constant for string (and other) hardcoded values.

This holds true for "magic numbers" and to a lesser extend random Strings. The reason to give them a meaningful name is to make things clear.

For example compare these 2 loop declarations:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   ... do stuff
}

for ( int i; i < MAX_BANANAS; i++) {
    ... do stuff
}
```

For the former you'll have to look through the entire loop before you hopefully realise why it's looping 5 times. The latter however shows you immediatly that you're doing something with a predefined amount of bananas.

Strings can have the same issue. If your XML had predefined business shortcuts instead of readable tags, defining them as constants at the top with an easily recognisable name would be the obvious preference. Since the best you could do was name them the same asside from a "KEY_" prefix there's not much added value here to do so. The only really useful constant is the filename, which following Doi9t's advice should probably be passed in as a parameter instead of being hard coded.

All that said, try to see what is more useful to you or other people actually using your code. Let's say you made a typo in one of the keys, how would you detect this? Would you debug the code right after reading the entire file, notice that there is *something* wrong but can't tell which input? Then putting them all together at the top would probably be more useful, as you can just go through them all easily to see which one has a type.

If you would easily figure out which field didn't get loaded in properly, then you'll probably jump into this file through the getter and can then see if the String defined there is correct instead of going a step further to the constant declaration (although in my IDE this is just 1 key press extra so doesn't change much either).

---

Style guidelines are usually just that: guidelines. It helps (me at least) to understand why those guidelines were written like that and see if they actually make sense before using them blindly.

Answer (score -1):

No, its not good idea to directly hard code the value in the method itself. 
Other way could be load all these values from resources properties file and use @value to load them inside your class.

Comment: It's not the value that's hard coded, but the key for the xml-element retrieval. As such this answer makes little sense...

Comment: There are some ways to load a properties file without using the keys, but you have to rely on the position of the element, but it's risky, since any modification to the order, or any modification can break the application. 

The only "@value" I know is in the Spring framework (use the hard-coded key anyway), since there's no indication that the person is using Spring, the constants are the best option in this case.